# How to solve "dead lock" situation of metro bundler - complaining either about naming collision or unable to resolve module

Tags: ios, react-native

I am working on a React Native app which includes a self-written React Native module included as local NPM module.

My NPM module as well as the React Native app including that NPM module, depend on React and React Native.

As a result, metro bundler is complaining about `naming collision` since the NPM packages are included twice.

To avoid that, I have added React and React Native in the self-written NPM module as peer dependencies.

However, if I do that, metro bundler is complaining that it is `unable to resolve module "react" / Module "react" does not exist in the Haste module map` of my self-written NPM package.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to move `react-native` (and maybe `react`) from the `dependencies` of your self-written module's `package.json` to `peerDependencies` instead.

Make sure `react` and `react-native` are in the `dependencies` of your *app’s* `package.json` and you should be good to go.

If your module needs `react-native` *outside* the context of an app, for tests or building, you can add it to `devDependencies` with no risk that it’ll be installed again into your host app.

`peerDependencies` are a way to represent that your module needs another module to be installed alongside it, but it's the responsibility of the host application to have the hard dependency and specify the version it wants.